# Spring Integration migration from 1.0.x to 2.2.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am migrating my project which was build on spring integration 1.0.x to 2.2.6 with spring framework 3.2.8

I have added the new JAR spring-integration-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar and removed the old one and also updated the xsd in my applicationContext.xml file.
Below is the xml schema details added in the applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:httpinvoker="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/httpinvoker"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.2.xsd">
```

Now I am facing some difficulties for the below case:

Below is a small section which was working fine in SI 1.0.x :

```
<channel id="msg.incoming">
        <queue capacity="600" />
</channel>

<service-activator input-channel="msg.incoming" ref="consumer"
        method="doPolling">
        <poller task-executor="consumerpool">
            <interval-trigger interval="1" time-unit="SECONDS" />
        </poller>
</service-activator>

<thread-pool-task-executor id="consumerpool"
        core-size="5" max-size="30" keep-alive-seconds="1000" queue-capacity="20" />
```

Now I want the same thing to be done with SI 2.2.6, After going through the SI docs, I have updated the above section with the below one:

```
<channel id="dnd.incoming">
        <queue capacity="600" />
    </channel>

<service-activator input-channel="dnd.incoming" ref="consumer" method="doDNDScrubbing">
        <poller fixed-delay="1000" />
</service-activator>
```

But unfortunately it is not working and also I am not able configure  like behavior in SI 2.2.6. 
​I am getting below exceptions:

```
BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A <poller> element must include either an <interval-trigger/> or <cron-trigger/> child element.
2014-04-18 11:55:07,254 ERROR main [ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A <poller> element must include either an <interval-trigger/> or <cron-trigger/> child element.
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.PollerParser.configureTrigger(PollerParser.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.PollerParser.parseInternal(PollerParser.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.IntegrationNamespaceHandler.parse(IntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.IntegrationNamespaceUtils.configurePollerMetadata(IntegrationNamespaceUtils.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractConsumerEndpointParser.parseInternal(AbstractConsumerEndpointParser.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.IntegrationNamespaceHandler.parse(IntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Please help me resolving this.

Regards,
Sandip Paul

Comment: Error message is clear `Configuration problem: A <poller> element must include either an <interval-trigger/> or <cron-trigger/> child element` which your config does not have

Comment: But <interval-trigger/> or <cron-trigger/> has been removed in SI 2.2.6. Do you know how to configure properly?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use versions for XSD at all. It will be easier to migrate to the new version.
2. Remove, please, unused xmlnses.
3. `<thread-pool-task-executor>` should be replaced with `<task:executor>`
4. > A `<poller>` element must include either an `<interval-trigger/>` or `<cron-trigger/>` child element.

It is a message from Spring Integration <= 2.0, not 2.2 =>. So, be sure that you use correct jars of Spring Integration.

All other configuration is OK.

Answer (score 1):

That is a big jump (1.0.x to 2.2.x).

Those child elements were deprecated in 2.0 and removed in 2.1.

Please review the migration guides [2.0->2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-2.0-to-2.1-Migration-Guide) and [2.1->2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-2.1-to-2.2-Migration-Guide). `3.0.2` is the current release; its [migration guide is here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-2.2-to-3.0-Migration-Guide).